# How to use DeviceId in Advertising Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, advertising-studio

Is it possible to use the device ID (the ID which is assigned to the phone when it's produced) in Advertising Studio in Audiences to increase the matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Device ID is related to an installation ID. There can be several device IDs related to a Contact Key, if you install / reinstall the App.

Plus, this Id is a MC data, which has no meaning for Facebook or any Social Network.

So passing this ID won't increase the matching (which is primarily based on email, and that you can refine with other parameters, but not the device ID).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that the Facebook Ads have possibility to match Mobile Advertiser ID during configuration. Maybe I can match this field with Device ID to increase the total matching

Comment: Those are not the same fields. One is related to MC and the installation ID, the other one is related to FB and its ad platform. They won't match, I'm afraid.